# ACR.UserDialogs UWP Toasts always show up in the top left corner

Tags: xamarin.forms, toast, xamarin.uwp

The title says it all. I have tried  `ToastConfig.DefaultPosition = ToastPosition.Bottom` but that has no effect. I have also tried setting the position every time I toast also to no avail. I've found other people with the same issue but never found an answer. I was hoping someone on here had encountered a similar issue and worked around it. I might add that the toasts work and look as expected on iOS and Android.

Comment: I met the same issue, I test `Acr.UserDialogs` 7.0.4 and `7.1.0.440` with xamarin forms nuget package 4.5.0.396. You have reported this issue in github, please  waitting for author's update:https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/issues/713

Comment: The author said that this is the intended design on UWP which I think just means he doesn't want to fix it. I ended up just making a custom control which is added as a UI element to the pages you want to toast. Not the most elegant solution but certainly the most customizable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author said that this is the intended design on UWP which I think just means he doesn't want to fix it. I ended up just making a custom control which is added as a UI element to the pages you want to toast. Not the most elegant solution but certainly the most customizable solution.